# Javascript assigning custom property keeps assigning indefinitely deep instead of once

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have some javascript where I'm trying to create a `promotion` within each of my promotion items. Right now though, for some reason it keeps on nesting itself indefinitely, and I only need it to contain one reference *(see screenshot)*

I've tried adding a check to see if `promotion.promotion` already exists and if it does to continue, but this just doesn't seem to run.

What am I missing?

```js
const promotions = [{
    title: 'My offer title',
  subtitle: 'lorem ipsum'
}, {
    title: 'My offer title 2',
  subtitle: 'lorem ipsum'
}, {
    title: 'My offer title 3',
  subtitle: 'lorem ipsum'
}]

for (const [index, promotion] of promotions.entries()) {
    if (promotion.promotion) continue
  promotion['promotion'] = promotion
}
```

Here's a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L53j4w0h/) for a demo.

[image]

This is what I need for the output:

```js
const promotions = [{
    title: 'My offer title',
  subtitle: 'lorem ipsum',
  promotion: {
    title: 'My offer title',
    subtitle: 'lorem ipsum',
  }
}, {
    title: 'My offer title 2',
  subtitle: 'lorem ipsum',
  promotion: {
    title: 'My offer title 2',
    subtitle: 'lorem ipsum',
  }
}, {
    title: 'My offer title 3',
  subtitle: 'lorem ipsum',
  promotion: {
    title: 'My offer title 3',
    subtitle: 'lorem ipsum',
  }
}]
```

Comment: Em, you've just done a circular reference. `promotion.promotion` is linking back to `promotion`. So if you go to that property, you get to promotion. Which also has a `.promotion` property. So if you go to that property, you get to `promotion`. Which also has a `.promotion` property. So if you go to that property, you get to `promotion`. Which also has a `.promotion` property. So if you go to that property, you get to `promotion`. Which also has a `.promotion` property...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (const [index, promotion] of promotions.entries()) {
    if (promotion.promotion) continue
  promotion.promotion = { ...promotion}
}
```